# How do I uninstall Nautilus-Elementary?

Tags: uninstall, nautilus-elementary

Looking at the associated packages, I'm concerned about breaking Nautilus if I try and uninstall Nautilus-Elementary. Can someone please advise me on the best way to remove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install [ppa-purge](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge) [image: Install ppa-purge].

   > This package provides a bash shell script capable of automatically downgrading all packages in a given PPA back to the ubuntu versions.
2. Run this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
   ```

Comment: on natty it doesn't work. also, what if i don't have the ppa anymore?

Comment: why can't I open that apt.ubuntu url from chrome... It only works from firefox.

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brave-apt/dists/loki/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason