# Nautilus Elementary wont show "main toolbar"

Tags: 10.10, nautilus-elementary

And it wont come back. Going to View > Main Toolbar has no effect ( it is always "on" ) and i dont see no buttons. Last thing i remember doing was installing elementary theme, then after i restarted,i saw no toolbar.

Comment: Have you tried View > Reset to Defaults from within Nautilus? Does switching themes help?

Comment: Yes, and reset wont help, and switching a theme doesnt help either

Answer (score 1):

The Elementary theme does not work correctly unless you have Nautilus Elementary installed.  Change your theme and your toolbar should come back.

Comment: That didn't help and i have nautilus-elementary

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in ubuntu 11.04 and just [uninstalled nautilus-elementary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16578/how-do-i-uninstall-nautilus-elementary)